# noUiSlider - wNumb formatting only first slider

Tags: javascript, plugins, formatting, nouislider

Using the wNumb.js plugin for noUiSLider, I'm trying to format the inputs on multiple sliders to appear as US dollars. The basic format object works for the first input but the second input and all other inputs that have sliders, show as empty. Also, the browser is not throwing any JavaScript errors.

Link to wNumb documentation: http://refreshless.com/wnumb/
Link to noUiSlider documentation: http://refreshless.com/nouislider/

Here is the basic noUiSlider code:

```
var slider_sales_vol = $('.range-slider-sales-vol'),
    slider_sales_vol_mas = $('.range-slider-sales-vol-mas'),
    AnnualVisaSales = $('#AnnualVisaSales'), guard = false,
    AnnualMasterCardSales = $('#AnnualMasterCardSales'), guard = false;

function setSalesValue(value){
    if ( guard ) return;
    $(this).val(value);
}

AnnualVisaSales.change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    guard = true;
    slider_sales_vol.val(value);
    guard = false;
});

AnnualMasterCardSales.change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    guard = true;
    slider_sales_vol_mas.val(value);
    guard = false;
});

var range_all_sliders = {
    'min': [ 1000, 1000 ],
    '33%': [ 100000,  50000 ],
    '66%': [ 500000, 100000 ],
    'max': [ 1000000 ]
};

$('.range-slider-sales-vol').noUiSlider({
    start: [ 1000 ],
    range: range_all_sliders,
    format: wNumb({
        decimals: 0,
        thousand: ',',
        prefix: '$ '
    })      
});

$('.range-slider-sales-vol-mas').noUiSlider({
    start: [ 1000 ],
    range: range_all_sliders,
    format: wNumb({
        decimals: 0,
        thousand: ',',
        prefix: '$ '
    })     
});

$('.range-slider-sales-vol').Link("lower").to(AnnualVisaSales, setSalesValue);
$('.range-slider-sales-vol-mas').Link("lower").to(AnnualMasterCardSales, setSalesValue);
```

Comment: Could you add the code you are using to display the value in the inputs?

Comment: I've updated the code, hopefully that provides more context.

Comment: @Lg102 does that context help? Would you like me to provide more?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was quite simple. The first input I have is 'type=text'. Because of this, it can easily be formatted with string data such as '$', '.', etc...All of the following inputs where 'type=number' which caused the noUislider formatting to be ineffective.